# What is speechletResponse?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Below is the response my API is sending Alexa:

```
{
    version: '1.0',
    sessionAttributes: {}
    response: {
        outputSpeech: {
           type: 'PlainText',
           text: "some text"
        },
       reprompt: {
          outputSpeech: {
          type: 'PlainText',
          text: "some text"
        }
    },
    shouldEndSession: false
  }

}
```

However when I look at the response in developer.amazon.com it has a additional property called "speechletResponse"

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "text": "Where are you planning to go ?",
      "type": "PlainText"
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "text": "some text",
        "type": "PlainText"
      }
    },
    "speechletResponse": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "text": "Where are you planning to go ?"
      },
      "reprompt": {
        "outputSpeech": {
          "text": "some text"
        }
      },
      "shouldEndSession": false
    }
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

I am not trasmitting this attribute, i can't seem to find anything about it in the docs, where is it coming from and what is it's utility ?